# Ratio of Water to Isopropyl Alcohol?

Tags: water, concentration, mixtures

I am looking for a very simple formula to calculate the ratio of water to 99% isopropyl alcohol that I need to prepare a solution with a density of 0.925 g/cm<sup>3</sup>. I am assuming there is one.

Comment: You'll also need a specific temperature.

Answer (score 3):

If performing an interpolation still passes as «simple» for you, you may find experimentally determined values about iPrOH in water tabulated for example in journals about (chemical) engineering.  The previews of [this](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/je60014a011) and [this](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1021/ja01438a004) give you about 10 entries for free (which may be complemented by the entries in the CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics like [here](https://archive.org/details/crchandbookofchemistryandphysics2016/page/n993)).  If more data are required, a more recent [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S1087659612050057) suggests going to a library and having a look into [Ullmann's Encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ullmann's_Encyclopedia_of_Industrial_Chemistry), too.

While keeping an eye on the temperature of the two, determine the volume of water and iPrOH to mix in separate containers in advance (1L of water and 1L of iPrOH don't add up to 2L of blend).

Answer (score -2):

There are no formula for calculating the density of a mixture water + any alcohol as a function of the proportion of water.

Comment: No theoretical formula, but an empirical one fit to experimental data might exist.